# @JdbcGetConnection not working in XPiNC after upgrade to 9.0.1 FP3 'SSLv3 SSLContext not available'

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

After upgrading Notes client to 9.0.1 FP3 I'm unable to get records from MS SQL instance. I got following error:

> Error while creating JDBC connection, url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.21.28\INSTANCENAME:1436;databaseName=dbname, username=username
>
> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SSLv3 SSLContext not available".
> SSLv3 SSLContext not available

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a ini setting to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that SSLv3 is currently enabled on the Windows server you are trying to connect to? See this question on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/644337/disabled-sslv3-to-combat-poodle-now-cannot-connect-to-sql-connection-forcibly-c

Comment: The reason of SSL handshake problems was an old jdbc driver... I was using sqljdbc4.jar from 2009. After replacing driver to most up to date version I was able to connect to MS SQL server on both client and server 9.0.1 FP3. 

The SSLv3 is disabled on sql server and encryption in connection string was off. The old driver was forcing to use SSLv3 SSLContext for the initial SSL handhake and failed because SSLv3 was disabled in JVM introduced in FP3.

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed [here](http://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/connected-session-slides-posted-bp102-practical-ibm-notes-and-domino-internet-security.htm), there are fixes related to SSL/TLS in 9.0.1 FP3. My best guess without further details is that defaults for this release are preventing handshake with your server because one of the recently disclosed vulnerabilities in SSL/TLS has not been patched on the server.