# JDBC driver not working for XPage after upgrade to 9.0.1 FP3

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpinc

I'm experiencing a problem connecting between Lotus Domino 9.0.1FP3 and a MSSQL database using the MS JDBC driver the same issue detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193943/jdbcgetconnection-not-working-in-xpinc-after-upgrade-to-9-0-1-fp3-sslv3-sslcon). Everything was fine in 9.0.1 but the applicaiton of FP3 has broken the link.

```
The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SSLv3 SSLContext not available". SSLv3 SSLContext not available
```

I've tried an upgrade of JDBC driver which didn't seem to make any difference  like it seems to have for TomSta in his comments

I've tried setting encrypt=true & trustServerCertificate=true which didn't seem to make any difference either.

Is there a change to the Domino / SQL / Windows servers that I need to make with to resolve this issue?

My code and the location of the error is shown below:

```
    public static ResultSet executeQuery(String connString, String userName, String pwd, String query) {

    //example connString: "jdbc:sqlserver://10.203.32.16;DatabaseName=DBTest";

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;
    Connection conn = null; 

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, userName, pwd); //Error occurs here
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if ( query != null ) {
            System.out.println("Failed SQL query: " + query);
        }
        try {
            if (rs != null) { rs.close(); }
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { rs = null; }
        try {
            if (st != null) { st.close(); }
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { st = null; }
        try {
            if (conn != null) { conn.close(); }
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { conn = null; }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return rs;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading to a Fixpack also causes the

```
<DominoBinary>\jvm\lib\security\java.policy
```

file to be changed to the default one, so if you changed something here (like for using Class.forName) you should add access granted to the class loader to work.
I don't know if that's a cause but sometimes error messages are not referring to the root cause.

By the way: we experienced that the jDTS driver has a better performance (and less bugs) than the Microsoft driver. You may have a look at it despite your problem. http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The java.policy file has currently been left as default on our servers so that shouldn't be the issue. I've tried switching over to use jDTS but this returns Error 403 - You are forbidden to perform this operation. Both sqljdbc4.jar and jtds-1.2.8.jar work on our other servers that are between 8.5.3 and 9.0.1 (without FP3). I've tried adding grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };  to the java.policy file with no success.

Answer (score 3):

This might have roots in SSLv3/TLS changes. Check this out:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2653857

[Does my JDBC connection to the database use SSL or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193177/does-my-jdbc-connection-to-the-database-use-ssl-or-not)